# how to pop a layer in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

please look the following picture

[image]

i want to do this function,when i click some button,it pop out a layer

my code is

```
-(id)init{
if (self = [super init]) {
    CCMenuItem *successbtn = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"success.png"
                                                     selectedImage:@"success.png"
                                                            target:self 
                                                          selector:@selector(successgame:)];
    CCMenu *ccMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:successbtn, nil];
ccMenu.position=ccp(950,700);
    [self addChild:ccMenu z:1 tag:2];
}
return self;
}

-(void)successgame:(id)sender{
    //how can i write here?
}
```

so how can i write?

Answer (score 0):

There is two possibilities. Either just add the button when you really want to show it and remove it from the Scenegraph as soon as it is not needed anymore.

Alternatively just make it invisible with the visible-property.